# How to cache Api Response via Angular Service Worker when api is on different domain

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular-service-worker

I am not able to cache my master data api via angular service worker
most of the examples show the url in dataGroup to be on same domain and hence only "/catalog" works
but my api is hosted on another domain

lets say its available at  http://x.com/api/catalog

following is ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ],
      "urls": [
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "xyz",
    "urls": ["http://x.com/api/catalog"],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 15,
      "maxAge": "1h",
      "timeout": "5s"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Here is a step by step tutorial, with a external api data source (https://www.random.org/): 

https://medium.com/bratislava-angular/service-workers-angular-3c1551f0c203.

You may have to do further configuration for CORS request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code in dataGroups works

the only thing is after loading the app either refresh or open a new tab for the service worker to cache

THe reason for this is given in the following link

https://blog.angular-university.io/service-workers/

in **Why isn't the Service Worker immediately active?** section

Comment: curious, did you configure your service worker manually like in the link, or did you use the cli and use ngsw-config.json?